# How can I change the opacity of the contents of a Swipe View during the time the swipe is opening in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to change the opacity as the swipe is in progress.  Are there any events which I could use for this and if so does anyone have any examples of how they have done this. What I would like is for the opacity of the swipe background to go from 100% to 0% when the swipe area is fully showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO !

I'm not sure whether this is your want , you can have a try with `SwipeEnded` and `SwipeChanging` to check .

The Xaml code( [based on the official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/) )  as follow :

```
...
<SwipeView SwipeEnded="SwipeView_SwipeEnded" SwipeChanging="SwipeView_SwipeChanging">
        <SwipeView.LeftItems>
            <SwipeItems SwipeBehaviorOnInvoked="Close"
                        Mode="Reveal">
                <SwipeItem Text="Favorite"
                            IconImageSource="favorite.png"
                            BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.FavoriteCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                            IconImageSource="delete.png"
                            BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </SwipeItems>
        </SwipeView.LeftItems>
 ...
```

The ContentPage will change the `Opacity` when `SwipeChanging` invoked .And when `SwipeEnded` invoked , set `Opacity` be `1` .

```
private void SwipeView_SwipeEnded(object sender, SwipeEndedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SwipeView_SwipeEnded");
    var swipView = sender as SwipeView;
    
    swipView.Opacity = 1;

}

private void SwipeView_SwipeChanging(object sender, SwipeChangingEventArgs e)
{
    var swipView = sender as SwipeView;
    
    swipView.Opacity = e.Offset/ swipView.Width;
}
```

The effect :

[image]